# Default filter value on column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I think I am missing some React or JavaScript knowledge to solve what I want to do.

**Background:**

- I have a table made with React Table.
- It has an input box filter for each column. The state in the component automatically takes in the query string and parses it into an object. The input boxes are automatically filled in when the page loads with the parsed query string.
- However, the data shown in the table is still all of the data, not the filtered data only. I have to go through each input box and press enter for it to be filtered by that value. So the value entered automatically into the input box is just for show

**My problem:**

I want the table to be filtered on load. But I can't figure out how to trigger the filter once when everything is loaded.

**The column headers code:**

```
//    ***Generate the column structure necessary for ReactTable
generateColumnHeaders(api_part_labels) {
    let label_array = []
    for (var key in api_part_labels) {
        const hasHeader = api_part_labels[key].includes(">")

        if (hasHeader) {
            label_array.push([api_part_labels[key].split(">")[0], api_part_labels[key].split(">")[1], key]);
        } else {
            label_array.push([api_part_labels[key], api_part_labels[key], key]);
        }
    }
    let mainHeaders = label_array.map((x) => x[0]);
    mainHeaders = Array.from(new Set(mainHeaders));
    let output = [];
    console.log(this.state.parsed);
    for (var i in mainHeaders) {
        let labels = label_array.filter(x => x[0] === mainHeaders[i]);

        if (labels.length === 1) {
            let param = labels[0][2];
            output.push({
                Header: labels[0][1],
                accessor: param,
                id: param,
                width: this.calculateColumnWidth(param, labels[0][1]),

            });
        } else {
            let columns = [];
            for (var i_label in labels) {
                var label = labels[i_label];
                let param = label[2];
                columns.push({
                    Header: label[1],
                    accessor: param,
                    id: param,
                    width: this.calculateColumnWidth(param, label[1]),
                    filteredValue: this.state.parsed[param],
                    Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) => {
                        return (
                            <input
                                onKeyPress={event => {
                                    if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
                                        let value = event.target.value;
                                        onChange(value);

                                        // update the parsed state with the event filter value
                                        this.updateParsed(param, value);

                                        // update 1) the query string, and 2) the URL
                                        let stringified = queryString.stringify(this.state.parsed);
                                        this.props.location.search = stringified;
                                        this.props.history.push(`?${stringified}`);
                                    }
                                }}
                                defaultValue={this.state.parsed[param]}
                            />
                        )},
                });
            }
            output.push({ Header: labels[0][0], columns: columns });
        }
    }

    return output;
};
```

**My React Table:**

```
return (
            <ReactTable
                // data and columns
                data = { this.parts }
                noDataText = "Whoops! No data available!"
                columns = { this.part_columns }

                // appearance
                defaultPageSize = {20}
                className = "-striped -highlight"
                style = {{ height: "800px" }}

                // sorting and filtering
                defaultSorted = {[ { id: "part_number", desc: false } ]}
                filterable
                defaultFilterMethod = {(filter, row) =>

String(row[filter.id]).toLowerCase().includes(filter.value.toLowerCase())}
            />
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need(ed) the `defaultFiltered` prop on ReactTable:

```
            defaultFiltered={[
              {
                id: 'reporting_year',
                value: new Date().getFullYear(),
              },
            ]}
```

I also wanted to customize the edit control in the filter box to be a drop-down containing the unique values in the column. As the documentation is pretty weak (or I'm slow and/or it's late), I'll include the column definition here too:

```
    {
      Header: 'Report Yr',
      accessor: 'reporting_year',
      Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) => {
        let found = {}
        let options = this.props.dashboard
          // remove duplicates
          .filter(function(row) {
            if (!found[row.reporting_year]) {
              found[row.reporting_year] = true
              return true
            }
            return false
          })
          // sort
          .sort((a, b) => (a.reporting_year > b.reporting_year ? 1 : b.reporting_year > a.reporting_year ? -1 : 0))
          // return option list
          .map(function(row) {
            return (
              <option value={row.reporting_year} key={row.reporting_year}>
                {row.reporting_year}
              </option>
            )
          })
        return (
          <select
            onChange={event => {
              onChange(event.target.value)
            }}
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
            value={filter ? filter.value : 'all'}>
            {options}
          </select>
        )
      },
    },
```

The default filter textbox is replaced with a drop-down with all the values in the data, defaulted to the `defaultFiltered` setting (in this case the current year).

Note that if you do not want the All option, this presentation isn't great, as the column can only ever contain a single value so is a waste of horizontal screen space.

To avoid repeating code for each column I created a higher order function. This is pretty handy - just set the `Filter` and `filterMethod` props on any column to switch the text filter to a drop-down containing all unique values.

```
class MyCmp extends Component {
  ...
  filterFn = accessor => ({ filter, onChange }) => {
    let found = {}
    let options = this.props.dashboard
      .filter(function(row) {
        if (row[accessor] && !found[row[accessor]]) {
          found[row[accessor]] = true
          return true
        }
        return false
      })
      .sort((a, b) => (a[accessor] > b[accessor] ? 1 : b[accessor] > a[accessor] ? -1 : 0))
      .map(function(row) {
        return (
          <option value={row[accessor]} key={row[accessor]}>
            {row[accessor]}
          </option>
        )
      })
    return (
      <select
        onChange={event => {
          onChange(event.target.value)
        }}
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        value={filter ? filter.value : 'all'}>
        <option value='all' key={'all'}>
          All
        </option>
        {options}
      </select>
    )
  }
  filterMethod = (filter, row, column) => {
    if (filter.value === 'all') {
      return true
    }
    const id = filter.pivotId || filter.id
    return row[id] !== undefined ? String(row[id]) === String(filter.value) : true
  }
```

Then to add a drop-down to a column, just add the `Filter` and `filterMethod` properties:

```
  columns = [
    {
      Header: 'CSP Code',
      accessor: 'csp_code',
      Filter: this.filterFn('csp_code'),
      filterMethod: this.filterMethod,
    },
    {
      Header: 'Report Yr',
      accessor: 'reporting_year',
      Filter: this.filterFn('reporting_year'),
      filterMethod: this.filterMethod,
    },
    ...
```

Note that this ignores empty cells - they only show when All is selected, and can't be filtered on. Also, it doesn't differentiate between '12' and 12, for example. It also ignores custom cells and filters on the underlying value - some of my cells are icons but the drop-downs display and filter on the underlying data values (this is desired behaviour for me, and acts as a kind of key to the icons).

[This example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/archives/v6-examples/react-table-custom-filtering) has some handy code samples and techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a function to filter your table's data inside a `componentDidMount()` method.

If you don't know what `compoenetDidMount()` method is, read this guide about [Lifecycle Events in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), this is one of the core concepts to understand in React to achieve some actions based on the document's triggered event.

Answer (score 0):

As said @Elharony, you need to set filtered by query items in `componentDidMount()`method -- i've done code for you [here](https://codepen.io/raliev/pen/MPerdg), see comments too, please.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user3759627, if you'll have any problems to set the query in `input` field, say - i didn't include this moment in written sample

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. But since the code you wrote is based on a <ul> instead of a <ReactTable>, I am still trying to make the translation. I am guessing that within my <ReactTable>, I should get rid of the fields "filterable" and "defaultFilterMethod". In the columns object I should add the logic with the initial items list and the updated lists under the Filter <input>? I will go ahead and try that and before that I will put more of my code in the question

Comment: @user3759627, i tried create sample based on your code, but don't know
 where you want to use your method `generateColumnHeaders()`? If you would paste minimal working part of your code anywhere (in codepen, f.e.), it will be much easier to work together and find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [example](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/controlled-component). You'd need to set `filtered={filteredData}` on your page load and may need to handle `onFilteredChange` as explained in the [FAQ](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-control-the-sortfilter-criteria-from-outside-of-my-react-table-instance-and-are-there-any-special-considerations-i-should-make-when-designing-my-code)

> If you intend to mix external sorting/filtering with user driven input from the table, you also need to consider handling onFilteredChange and onSortedChange. Your code will need to be intelligent around which input (the programmatic or user) takes precedence).

Answer (score -1):

Try to render your table after data was loaded. You can add simple loader which is default switch on, load your data and after successful load switch loader off. And render table only when loader is switch off.